# how to send python file to docker container(using python image) and get the output back to local

Tags: python-3.x, docker, sdk

i have a program which fetches the python code as string. How can i get it executed in python container every time it is fetched and get the output back to local??

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile?

Comment: i just created the container using python image on dockerhub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this via docker yml (docker-copose)

```
services:
  server:
    command: bash -c "python3 manage.py migrate; python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000; tail -f /dev/null;"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Or in Dockerfile:

```
RUN python3 manage.py migrate
```

If the python code is a string maybe try using EVAL command:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval